# How to create standalone module with webpack usable through script element?

Tags: javascript, npm, package, webpack, babeljs

Thought if the library target was set to 'umd' that outputs would be usable via a `<script>` tag and if no module system was available it would be attached to the window. However this doesn't seem to be the case or a mistake has been made somewhere.. need another pair of eyes at this point.

package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "scoped-css",
  "version": "2.1.9",
  "description": "Scoped CSS in two easy steps.",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "author": "Joshua Robinson",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/buildbreakdo/scoped-css.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/buildbreakdo/scoped-css/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/buildbreakdo/scoped-css",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "reactive-root",
    "scope",
    "scoped",
    "inline",
    "style",
    "styles",
    "styling",
    "css",
    "CSS",
    "classes",
    "classname",
    "classnames",
    "util",
    "utility"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-jest": "^12.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
    "jest-cli": "^12.1.1",
    "js-beautify": "^1.6.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack && babel src --out-dir lib && NODE_ENV='production' webpack && babel src --out-dir lib && npm run tests",
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist lib",
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "tests": "npm run lint && jest --coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

webpack.config.js is:

```
// => webpage.config.js

var webpack = require('webpack');

var __DEV__ = JSON.parse(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: __DEV__ ? 'dist/scoped-css.js' : 'dist/scoped-css.min.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'scoped-css'
  },
  plugins: __DEV__ ? [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ] : [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

However when including the module via a `<script>` tag and try to use the code seeing a:

```
standalone.html:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Style is not defined
```

`standalone.html` is the following:

```
<!-- standalone.html -->

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="../dist/scoped-css.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li>baz</li>
            <li>klutz</li>
        </ul>

        <script>
            var ulElements = document.querySelectorAll('ul');

            var firstUlElement = ulElements[0];
            firstUlElement.className = Style.scoped();
            var firstUlStyle = document.createElement('style');
            firstUlStyle.type = 'text/css';
            firstUlStyle.innerHTML = Style.CSS( { 'li' : { color: 'red' } } );
            document.head.appendChild(firstUlStyle);

            var secondUlElement = ulElements[1];
            secondUlElement.className = Style.scoped();
            var secondUlStyle = document.createElement('style');
            secondUlStyle.type = 'text/css';
            secondUlStyle.innerHTML = Style.CSS( { 'li' : { backgroundColor: 'khaki' } } );
            document.head.appendChild(secondUlStyle);

            // See how both styles target all li? They do not impact each other
            // because each is scoped--this is called subtree scoping and is natively
            // supported in Firefox; native support has not landed in other browsers yet
            // so this serves as a poly-like-fill.
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the top and bottom part of `../dist/scoped-css.js` (have checked the network panel, it is loading correctly, just is not available to be called):

```
// => dist/scoped-css.js

(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory();
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define([], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["scoped-css"] = factory();
    else
        root["scoped-css"] = factory();
})(this, function() {
return /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

...
...
...

        if (true) {
            // Add support for AMD ( https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD#defineamd-property- )
            !(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ = [__webpack_require__, __webpack_require__(2), __webpack_require__(1)], __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ = function(requireamd) {
                var js_beautify = __webpack_require__(2);
                var css_beautify = __webpack_require__(1);

                return {
                    html_beautify: function(html_source, options) {
                        return style_html(html_source, options, js_beautify.js_beautify, css_beautify.css_beautify);
                    }
                };
            }.apply(exports, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__), __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ !== undefined && (module.exports = __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__));
        } else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
            // Add support for CommonJS. Just put this file somewhere on your require.paths
            // and you will be able to `var html_beautify = require("beautify").html_beautify`.
            var js_beautify = require('./beautify.js');
            var css_beautify = require('./beautify-css.js');

            exports.html_beautify = function(html_source, options) {
                return style_html(html_source, options, js_beautify.js_beautify, css_beautify.css_beautify);
            };
        } else if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            // If we're running a web page and don't have either of the above, add our one global
            window.html_beautify = function(html_source, options) {
                return style_html(html_source, options, window.js_beautify, window.css_beautify);
            };
        } else if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
            // If we don't even have window, try global.
            global.html_beautify = function(html_source, options) {
                return style_html(html_source, options, global.js_beautify, global.css_beautify);
            };
        }

    }());

/***/ }
/******/ ])
});
;
```

Suspicion is that it has something to do with how the exports is being handled in `src/index.js` (original file before building to `dist/scoped-css.js`).

Bottom of `src/index.js` (before build) looks like:

```
// Index.js
...
...
...
var Style = {
        scoped: scoped,
        CSS: CSS
    };

module.exports = Style;
```

Again, expectation is that if `../dist/scoped-css.js` in a script tag is included then `scoped-css.js` could be called like `Style.CSS({})` or `Style.scoped()` (attached to window).

Additionally, use jest for testing and the module loads and is callable just fine, so know the code isn't broken. Something is up with webpack config?

Likely something foolish on my part, just need another set of eyes, been staring at this too long! Thanks for your time and expertise.

Comment: Have you tried setting `library: 'Style'` instead of `library: 'scoped-css'`?

Comment: You are a god amongst men to catch that one line in this giant dump of code. 100% correct, please post that as an answer so I can give you credit. Thank you so much @bebraw !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your UMD build outputs using `scoped-css` global due to that `library: 'scoped-css'` line. If you change it to `library: 'Style'`, the code will work as you expect.